# getting all td in a variable

Tags: jquery

how do i get all the first td in a variable of following table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="myTable">
         <tr >
        <td>785.1 </td>
        <td>do not pick me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>427.31</td>
        <td>do not pick me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>780.2</td>
        <td>do not pick me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Fabrizio *... of following table*. I suppose this supports the first option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
var tds = $(".myTable td:first-child");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/S2N5n/

Comment: I think he means the first TD of each TR. It seems he wants multiple.

Comment: @Flater the first td of each tr will allways be the first-child

Comment: Ah nvm, does the first-child takes into account the direct parent (TR) or the selector used (.myTable) ? Not sure anymore.

Comment: @Flater It does. `:first` does not, `:first-child` does.

Comment: thanks this works, I'll mark it as answer as soon as this time limit gets over.

Comment: can u tell me how do i get immediate tr of any particular td?

Comment: @okay If you mean parent TR, then use `parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the first TD element of each TR element within the table?

```
var fields = $("#myTable>tr>td:first-child");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
var Firsttds = $(".myTable tr td:first-child");
alert(Firsttds.length)​;​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first  of each  for table you gave in question as follows ,

```
    var firstTDS    =   $(".myTable tr td:first-child");
```

This is a list of first  of each  , you can process them by traversing firstTDS . For example to change background color of first  of each  , you can do ,

```
   for(var i in firstTDS)
   {
     $(firstTDS[i]).css('background-color','red');
   }
```

That's it .